# What does "third-party in the context of "third-party application" mean?

Tags: terminology

I would like to know what does "third-party software" mean? Some people usually talk about "third-party apps" too. What does "third-party" mean in those contexts?

Answer (score 6):

Third party refers to a another company making software for the original vendors product

For example: nearly all iPhone Apps are created by third-parties (not by Apple itself)

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_software_component)

> In computer programming, third party
>   software component is a reusable
>   software component developed to be
>   either freely distributed or sold by
>   an **entity other than the original
>   vendor** of the development platform.
>
> The third party software component
>   market thrives because component
>   oriented development improves the
>   efficiency and quality of developing
>   custom applications.

Answer (score 3):

First Party is the OS manufacturer, for example Microsoft with Windows. Second Party is the user (you). Third Party is the manufacturer of other software or hardware, e.g. Adobe with Photoshop and Flash.

Answer (score 1):

If you (the first party) were to pay this website, superuser.com (the second party) to get your questions answered and superuser.com were in turn to pay the "experts" to answer those questions, then those experts would be the "third party" - who do not actually belong to who you paid the money (superuser.com), but in turn get paid by them for their service.

Comment: this does not really answer your question directly about "software" and "applications", but that's the concept.